# Codeigniter: facebook messanger in site, fine with desktop and mobile phones also. But if fb app installed in mobile then cause blank page issue

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have integrated facebook messanger with codeigniter website.

everything is working properly.. for desktop and mobile phones also..

**but if fb app installed in mobile, then fb messanger cause blank page redirect issue**

My code snippet:

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.2'
   });
   };

   (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

   <!-- Your customer chat code -->
   <div class="fb-customerchat"
     attribution=setup_tool
     page_id="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
     greeting_dialog_display="hide">
   </div>
```

please suggest me the changes to solve this..

Comment: I don’t think there is anything you can do from your end to fix that. The Facebook in-app browser appears to be a complete catastrophe. Facebook might pretend that it was a full-fledged mobile browser, but apparently it isn’t - the number of issues with stuff that is not working in there, is legend by now.

Comment: You can file a bug report and ask Facebook to fix this, https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs Whether they will want to, will even be able to - dunno.